# awk 'FNR == 2 {print}' issue

Tags: linux, awk

I have some task on which i need to know the install date of WLS which is located in second row of file called `envVars.properties` which is located in `/opt/weblogic1221/wlserver_12.2.1/installation/install/envVars.properties`.
I have server which has multiple versions of WL there for I use `*` in `/opt/weblogic*/wlserver*/...`.
But when I run `cat /opt/weblogic*/wlserver*/installation/install/*.properties| awk 'FNR == 2 {print}'`
I get only 1 result (for the first file it finds).

See:

```text
[root@server090 ~]# cat /opt/weblogic*/wlserver*/installation/install/*.properties| awk 'FNR==2{print}'
#Mon Feb 02 14:47:02 IST 2015
```

Without `awk`:

```text
[root@server90 ~]# cat /opt/weblogic*/wlserver*/installation/install/*.properties
#Copyright (c) 1999, {0}, Oracle. All rights reserved.
#Mon Feb 02 14:47:02 IST 2015
JAVA_HOME_CCR=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_72
#Copyright (c) 1999, 2016, Oracle. All rights reserved.
#Mon Feb 06 15:35:50 IST 2017
JAVA_HOME_CCR=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_102
```

There are 2 files as you can see:

```text
[root@server90 ~]# ll /opt/weblogic*/wlserver*/installation/install/*.properties
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle dba 121 Feb  2  2015 /opt/weblogic1213/wlserver_12.1.3/installation/install/envVars.properties
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle dba 123 Oct 20  2017 /opt/weblogic1221/wlserver_12.2.1/installation/install/envVars.properties
```

Comment: `cat` concatenates input files, therefore `awk` only sees one stdin as the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't "cat through to awk", just specify the files after the `awk` statement and so:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print}' /opt/weblogic*/wlserver*/installation/install/*.properties
```

Using `cat` is needless and it will merge all input files into one single output, so `awk` will just see one input file (`FNR` can only match once, then).

Comment: `{print}` is redundant - that;'s the default behavior.